# Will there be a The Year's Best Science Fiction: Thirty-Sixth Annual Collection?

Tags: anthology-book, publishing, the-years-best-science-fiction, gardner-dozois

Will one be published? *The Year's Best Science Fiction* has been an annual Xmas gift for 35 years. Was confused when I got *The Very Best of the Best*. Only to realize Gardner Dozois died in 2018!  Any publisher taking over? I searched St. Martin's Griffin to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously there won't be a 36th annual edited by Dozois.  Just like *Year's Best SF* didn't outlive Hartwell by much. (And only that because Kathryn Cramer had been doing a lot of the work and was able to carry it on for a few years.)

That said, there are other collections and I have no doubt that any story that Dozois would have selected will find a home.

For pure science fiction you might try Neil Clarke's [*The Best Science Fiction of the Year*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?42005).  If you don't mind a mixed science fiction/fantasy anthology there's one by Rich Horton ([*The Year's Best Science Fiction & Fantasy*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?27939)) and one by Jonathan Strahan ([*The Best Science Fiction and Fantasy of the Year*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?23931)).